# WooCommerce Rest API get products by slug

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-rest-api

New to WooCommerce, and using the REST API to get products which I have successfully done.

Not sure on how to get a single product using the `slug` as permalink gives full url, where as i only need the end slug so I can have clean urls and not use the `id` to find a record. I know with the Wordpress rest api plugin you can do this `posts-api?filter[name]==` and get the post by product slug, rather than use:

```
/wc-api/v3/products/id
```

I want to be able to do:

```
/wc-api/v3/products/slug
```

Answer (score 8):

You just have to adjust the query slightly `/wc-api/v3/products/slug` should be `/wc-api/v3/products/?slug=your-product-slug`.

One important difference is that this will return the slug inside an array, so you will have to select the first object in the array once you have parsed it.